# Download files from FTP or HTTP using filenames in CSV - Python 3

Tags: csv, python-3.x, ftp, urllib

I have a csv file of products for an ecommerce site I'm working on, as well as FTP access to the corresponding images for each product (~15K products).

I would like to use Python to pull only the images listed in the csv from either the FTP or HTTP and save them locally.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

url='http://www.fakesite.com/pimages/filename.jpg'

split = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
filename = split.path.split("/")[-1]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

print(filename)

saveFile = open(filename,'r')
saveFile.close()

import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    images = []

    for row in readCSV:
        image = row[14]

print(image)
```

The code I have currently can pull the filename from the URL and save the file as that filename. It can also pull the filename of the image from the CSV file. (filename and image are the exact same) What I need it to do, is input the filename, from the CSV into the end of the URL, and then save that file as the filename.

I have graduated to this:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import os
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    images = []

    for row in readCSV:
        image = row[14]

        images.append(image)


x ='http://www.fakesite.com/pimages/'

url = os.path.join (x,image)

split = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
filename = split.path.split("/")[-1]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,filename)



saveFile = open(filename,'r')
saveFile.close()
```

Now this is great. It works perfectly. It is pulling the correct filename out of the CSV file, adding it on to the end of the URL, downloading the file, and saving it as the filename.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to make this work for more than one line of the CSV file. As of now, it takes that last line, and pulls the relevant information. Ideally, I would use the CSV file with all of the products on it, and it would go through and download every single one, not just the last image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing strange things ...

```
import urllib.request
import csv

# the images list should be outside the with block
images = []
IMAGE_COLUMN = 14

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    # read csv
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in readCSV:
        # I guess 14 is the column-index of the image-name like 'image.jpg'
        # I've put it in some constant  

        # now append all the image-names into the list
        images.append(row[IMAGE_COLUMN])

        # no need for the following
        # image = row[14]
        # images.append(image)

# make sure, root_url ends with a slash
# x was some strange name for an url
root_url = 'http://www.fakesite.com/pimages/'

# iterate through the list
for image in images:
    # you don't need os.path.join, because that's operating system dependent.
    # you don't need to urlsplit, because you have created the url yourself.
    # you don't need to split the filename as it is the image name
    # with the following line, the root_url must end with a slash
    url = root_url + image

    # urlretrieve saves the file as whatever image is into the current directory
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, image)
```

or in short, that's all you need:

```
import urllib.request
import csv

IMAGE_COLUMN = 14
ROOT_URL = 'http://www.fakesite.com/pimages/'
images = []

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in readCSV:
        images.append(row[IMAGE_COLUMN])

for image in images:
    url = ROOT_URL + image
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, image)
```

Comment: Wow. That worked beautifully. I apologize for doing some odd things, I'm very new to Python. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This poses my next question, which I've posted below.